# MongoDB/mongoid update_attributes method slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have some code where I need to update a record in my mongoDB DB.  So I first find the record and then I update the record.  However, the records have lots of text data stored with them, so I don't want to retrieve the entire document when I get it back; just enough so that I can update it.  I thought that if I used the "only(...)" method in mongoid, that this would return only that attribute.  These queries seem to be running very slow, though, so I was not sure if they were accomplishing what I thought they were accomplishing.

```
d = Document.only(:title).find(title) # using 'title' as key in mongoDB
d.update_attributes({ author: "author_name" })
```

Is there a faster way to execute this desired query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB offers a number of highly-optimized modifier operations. Look into using the `$set` operation to set only a single key without having to deal with the rest of the document. You can also do the update and the query in a single operation. A native MongoDB query to update the `author` of all records with the specified `title` would look like this:

```
var title = "The Title"
db.documents.update( { title: title }, { $set: { author: "The Author" } } )
```

Hopefully you can find a way to pass that query along through Mongoid. If not, you can go directly down to the native Mongo adapter to run it.  For more info, see the [docs on modifier operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations).

Comment: Adding onto answer, `Document.where(title: title).update_all(author: "The Author")`. But this will skip the validations.

Comment: That's functionally equivalent to what jacobra is doing currently. It's the `$set` operator that allows updating part of a record without fetching the whole thing.

Comment: This query gets translates to `$set` without fetching the document. Just a nicer syntax :)

Comment: Ah, ok. That's my lack of familiarity with Mongoid, then. Sounds like the best solution if it automatically uses `$set`. Thanks.

Comment: @Rubish Gupta: so you're saying that if you run the query

  Document.where(title: title).update_all(author: "Author")

That mongoid will translate this into a single query that updates the record?  I had seen this before but thought it was running multiple queries.  If this is true, then this definitely looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, I mean to say that only, you can confirm by looking at your development.log while you fire the query.

Answer (score 0):

One thought I have is that you could break up the collection into two collections: one that has the metadata of the text (name, author, yearPublished, numPages, etc), and another that has a foreign key(which could just be MongoDB's _id) and the text itself.  Then you can modify things like author name on the smaller collection, which I believe would perform faster...  Something to test, I guess.  However, I think your speed issues are due to the size of records.  I personally noticed a significant loss in performance going from a simple test dataset without many attributes to a real dataset with many attributes per record.